# jQuery Selector for file inputs with at least one file assigned

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page with several file inputs.  The files are optional to the end user.  I want to select the inputs that actually have a file assigned to them.  The code I have now is similar to this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file1" value="File 1"/>
<input type="file" id="file2" value="File 2"/>
<input type="file" id="file3" value="File 3"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
  if(this.files.length > 0){
    //do something with this file
  }
});
```

That's not terrible, but I'd really like to incorporate the "files.length>0" in the selector itself.  I've tried this:

```
$('input[type="file"][value!=""]')
```

But it selects every file input, regardless of whether a file is assigned.  What's the magic word for selecting only assigned file inputs?

Comment: Can't be done by selector because the files are properties not attributes

Comment: @Mech `this.files` is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the files property by selector

Using `filter()` before `each` is an option.

```
$('input[type="file"]').filter(function(){
   return this.files && this.files.length;
}).each(function(){
 // do something with files
});
```

Comment: Frankly that seems worse than just doing the if() inside the .each(), but you did give me an answer, so thank you.

Comment: Yeah The simple `if()` is really just as easy

Comment: If you had to do this  lot there is an easy way to write a pseudo selector such as `:files` that would extend the jQuery object and be useable anywhere in that code base

Comment: good point @charlieftl.  i haven't had this come up before ,but if it does come up again, i'll look at making a small extension.